# React onFocus and onFocusCapture difference

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I was wondering what is the difference between react events: `onFocus` and `onFocusCapture`. I could not find an appropriate answer on react's documentation page.

```
<OutlinedInput
    label="price from"
    onFocus={handlePriceFocus}
/>
<OutlinedInput
    label="price to"
    onFocusCapture={handlePriceFocus}
/>
```

In my case, it seems like `onFocus` and `onFocusCapture` do the same functionality because I have not noticed any difference when using those two events.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is what React say in their documentation:

> "The event handlers below are triggered by an event in the bubbling phase. To register an event handler for the capture phase, append Capture to the event name; for example, instead of using onClick, you would use onClickCapture to handle the click event in the capture phase."
> https://react.dev/learn/responding-to-events#capture-phase-events

So, I think there isn't anymore to say about that. What I understand it's like without 'capture' the code is executed after the event and with 'capture' it's executed before.